# Is there a way to set up custom global output formatting for timestamptz values?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, postgresql-13

In order to reduce friction between frontend/backend/database in regards of dates, I've decided to use a subset of `RFC3339` which is also compatible with `ISO 8601` and `HTML`. As per [this graph](https://ijmacd.github.io/rfc3339-iso8601/) that means `T` is a mandatory delimiter. However [none of default formatting styles](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT-TABLE) include it. And the there is [no config option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) which include it either.
I've read [datetime](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-datetime.html) and [their formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-formatting.html) articles and it looks like `to_char()` is what I need. But the problem is it requires to be called on every `timestamptz` column in every query, of which there are plenty because almost all tables at least have auto-generated creation and update timestamps and some outputs include json object columns with datetime values, so that's a lot of seemingly random calls all over the place just to keep output in sync.
So what is the way to format `RFC3339` and `ISO 8601` and `HTML` conformant `timestamptz` values with as little friction as possible?

Comment: You should do the formatting in your program code, that processes the results of the SQL query. SQL isn't really the best place to format data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Why not format my output in SQL? Typically, that's simpler and faster than processing results a second time in the client. There are good reasons why Postgres provides its rich arsenal of formatting tools.

Comment: Note that [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6) explicitly allows a space instead of the separator `T`: *"NOTE: ISO 8601 defines date and time separated by "T".
 Applications using this syntax may choose, for the sake of
 readability, to specify a full-date and full-time separated by
 (say) a space character."* (But the latest ISO 8601 standard does not.) Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9531524/939860

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: because if you format the data in SQL, everything arrives as a string in the application which - at least in my experience - is not a good thing. The data should arrive as the native data type in the application (integers as integers, dates as dates, timestamps as timestamps and so on). And typically things are formatted differently depending on e.g. the user's locale or even the context in which the value is displayed - again something that can't really be done in the backend.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: OK, to keep operating with original data types, you've got a point. But if the requirement is to get data in a certain format then, by all means, format in SQL right away. I disagree with the generalized statement *"SQL isn't really the best place to format data."*.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I can format in the application code, yes, but the issue is Postgresql not being able to output the datetime strings in a most compatible format (despite accepting them just fine). Using `T` instead of a white space changes no semantics of the datetime string, but ensures a lot less parsers will choke on it when passed around.
Also hell no about native datatypes. Every language has its own opinion on integers/dates (their serializability and compatibility with similar SQL type vary) but almost all of them know what a utf-8 JSON string is.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter `RFC3339` allows it to be optional, but `ISO 8601` and `HTML` do not. So clearly the most compatible format is the one with `T` at least.